# Can every liquid pure substance be compressed to solid?

Tags: phase, pressure

Apart form the fact that liquid are often misleadingly considered incompressible,
fact that I recently find out to be true only as an approximation in specific circumstances.
I was curious to know if it's a property of all elements that they can be turned from liquid to solid by applying pressure.
In fact by looking at the different phase diagrams and at the general one, seems an intrinsic property of the elements the capacity of becoming solid under some pressure. 
A description of what happens at the atomic level, addressing the reasons for the phenomena would be appreciated too.

Comment: Water is no exception: it **does** become solid under high pressure.

Comment: Presuming your mention of water is because of the fact that the solid is less dense then the liquid (at normal atmospheric pressure), it turns out that water really isn't that weird. Elements with the same property include Si, Ge, Bi, and Sb. However, as noted by @IvanNeretin, they all are solids at high pressures, in part at least because they assume more densely packed crystal structures eventually.

Comment: From the diagram I see it seems that water can become solid from gas but not from liquid (under high pressure)...Instead it can become liquid from solid..Can you link me to your diagrams?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water#Melting_point

Comment: Consider neutronium...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It may be fluid, but not liquid.